# Password protection for software uninstallation/deletion

Tags: python, windows, macos, uninstallation, password-protection

I am building a python app for windows and macOS. I need to protect it from tamper-proofing - Only when users give an authentication password, they should be able to uninstall or delete the package. Is there any third-party software that can help with this? Or how should I go about writing code for the same?
All users have elevated admin privileges So it's not possible to deploy the app as an admin. End users would be able to elevate their privileges and uninstall the app. But I don't want this to happen.
Additionally, the deployment of the app will be managed by an automated software deployment mechanism, that does a soft push of the software to all systems.
The app is expected to run in the background, without the knowledge of the end-user. The end-user should not be able to tamper with the running process or uninstall / delete the app

Comment: All users have elevated admin privileges  So it's not possible to deploy the app as an admin. End users would be able to elevate their privileges and uninstall the app. But I don't want this to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Open Control Panel and go to administrative tools and open Local Security Policy app, Select "Local Policies" folder and inside that folder go to "Security Options Folder" and double click "User Account Control: Behaviour of the elevation prompt for administrators in Admin Approval Mode" and change the policy from "Prompt for consent for non-Windows binary to "Prompt for Credentials on the secure desktop" and click apply and ok.

Comment: Thank you IT- Cyber-227. All users have elevated admin privileges. So this doesn't help us.